# Unique URL for POST submission

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am an inexperienced amateur web developer, so please forgive me if I'm missing an obvious solution to this problem.

My website consists of a search form that is used to search through information I've made available in a static database. There are several parameters in the search form, so the form uses `POST` to send the parameters to the page. When a valid search occurs, the parameters of the search are logged in a mySQL table with an associated unique auto-incremented ID. When the results are displayed, a link of the form `index.php?id=100&page=1` is also displayed so the search can be accessed again without re-inputting the parameters.

However, since `POST` is used to send the parameters, the URL after the search remains `index.php`. Is there any way I can send that unique ID to the URL after the search so that the URL after the search is displayed as `index.php?id=100&page=1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, either of the following will accomplish what you want:

1. Use a `GET` request rather than a `POST` request.
2. Have the server redirect the user to a new page which has the parameters in the `GET` string.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/3108853 for details on redirecting).